# Yii2 can not find model file

Tags: linux, yii2

I have the following directories and files in them:

```
- backend
   - models
        Book.php

- frontend

- common
   - OOP
      CommonController.php
```

book.php

```
class Book extends ActiveRecord
{
...
}
```

commonController.php

```
  public function actionIndex()
  {
    $path="backend\\models\\Book";
    $model=$path::find();
  }
```

In Windows OS it works fine. But in Linux line of `$model=$path::find();` throws an error:

```
'backend\models\Book' not found
```

So, I changed `$path` to "backend/models/Book". But, still, I have the following error:

```
'backend/models/Book' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in case sensitivity.

The file with class `Book` should be named `Book.php`. Paths in windows are case-insensitive so it works fine. But in Linux, they are case-sensitive so autoloader looks for class in file `backend/models/Book.php` which doesn't exist.

The format `backend\models\Book` in your code is right because this is not filepath but fully qualified name which uses backslash as namespace separator.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for the late answer. But, Book.php is the same in Linux and Windows (post edited and changed book.php to Book.php).

Comment: Actually, My model name is CulturalAttachmentContributor and the file name is also CulturalAttachmentContributor.php. I named Book here for simplification.